# User autoscrolling is blocking Javascript callbacks in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

When scrolling by autoscrolling (middle mouse button and dragging on a webpage) on the chrome browser, it seems that callbacks aren't happening until the user releases the button.

I'm trying to lazy load table rows through AJAX requests and it is preventing the table from populating.

This only happens on chrome and seems to work fine in firefox.

Why is this happening and is there a workaround for it?

For example:

```
let canFireRequest = true;

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if (canFireRequest) {
        const scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        const scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();

        if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight <= 0.15) {

            populateRows(tableView, onLoadBeforePopulate);

            canFireRequest = false;
            setTimeout(function () { //execution reaches this line
                canFireRequest = true; //but this is only called when MMB is released
            }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which events are you attaching your callbacks to?

Comment: @f-CJ For example I call setTimeout somewhere in the scroll callback and the execution reaches this, but the callback for setTimeout doesn't execute until the button is released. (I'll edit the question to show an example)

Comment: It's also not just setTimeout, the callback of jQuery's getJson also waits for MMB up

Comment: The getJson actually sends the network request so it's not as if something is hogging the main loop, it's just the callback from it which is being blocked. I might try implementing it with intersection observer API, to see if that works any smoother.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a bug in chrome that was introduced recently because of optimisations in input scheduling, and hopefully will be fixed sometime later this year. See the bug report here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=874072#c_ts1534324198